# Button that launches map activity and also animates/moves Camera to specific location there…

Tags: android, mapactivity

I have a button that launches a *new activity (map activity)*, and I want it also to *animate/move camera* to a specific location/place after the *new* *activity(map activity)* launches... with the code below it only launches the *new activity (map activity).*

```
public void openPlace(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

I Don't know What code to add (I am New to Coding) thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest reading the Getting Started guide for Google Maps before continuing, especially step 5. There are plenty of code samples there that should get you started: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: Search 1.How to get current location in android 2. How to zoom map to a particular location android

Comment: I know how to zoom map to a particular location but I want button to open new activity and move camera to a particular location because I have way more buttons and I don't want to do a new activity (map activity) for each button

Comment: In which case, add the latitude, longitude and zoom level as `Intent` extras  to the intent you're sending (assuming you're using different intents for each button), retrieve those extras from `getIntent()` in `MapActivity` and feed them into your map in `onMapReady()`.